# Find URLs in String, JQUERY

Tags: jquery, regex

I have some function to grab all the urls found in a string, which works great and as it should. However, it's not grabbing the full URL with segments, if they exist (i.e. http://domain.com/somepage/stuff, http://goo.gl/ew34r, http://bit.ly/w9r34, etc.). It'll just pull the base domain, not any trailing URL segments.

How can I modify my regex to include all url segments if they exists?

`var urls = text.match(/\b(http|https)?(:\/\/)?(\S*)\.(\w{2,4})\b/ig);`

The above needs to extract all URL variations, such as:

```
www.domain.com
domain.com
http://www.domain.com
http://www.domain.com/somepage
http://www.domain.com/somepage/morepage
http://www.domain.com/somepage/morepage/*
www.domain.com/somepage
www.domain.com/somepage/morepage
www.domain.com/somepage/morepage/*
domain.com/somepage
domain.com/somepage/morepage
domain.com/somepage/morepage/*
```

URIs can include numbers obviously.

Comment: from your stamen |How can I take just the domain if that's all that exists...or the full URI?| why do you need a regex? if you read a line you get a domain or full URL without a regex

Comment: Huh? I'm grabbing the domain from a textarea that was user inputted and contents random text along with URLS.

Comment: @ErikS no idea what you're talking about man.

Comment: in your example you have a list of urls or domain names. You require to grab the domain or the full URL.. the list structure matches your requirements.. or I do really need a nap :S

Comment: If there's a domain of `http://www.domain.com/page`, it will only grab `http://www.domain.com`...leaving out the `/page`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After struggling a bit, i got it.

```
var sumbittedUrls ="test.com http://another.us/one/1/three/four/five/six";

var urls = sumbittedUrls.match(/\b(http|https)?(:\/\/)?(\S*)\.(\w{2,4})(.*)/g);
console.log(urls);
//log -> ["test.com http://another.us/one/1/three/four/five/six"]
```

This is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bellu/4vsgq8dr/1/).